# Nested Control & Simulation Loops in LabView

Tags: labview

Trying to simulate a motor in LabView to be run in real-time on a MyRIO.

I've split the whole model into multiple VIs to make life easier. The main VI has a Control & Simulation loop with timing parameters synchronised so that it runs in real-time.

Within one of the sub-VIs there is another Control & Simulation loop. How do I synchronise that with the one in the main VI? Is it an allowable practice? I can't really seem to find much information regarding it.

Also, is it possible to have a "start" button for a Control & Simulation loop? There's a few parameters that I want to be able to change before the loop starts.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question:
it is possible to configure a trigger so that a Subsystem executes only when certain conditions are met.

See [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371894G-01/lvsimconcepts/sim_c_subsys/#Running_a_Subsystem_Outside_a_Simulation_Loop) in section "Enabled and Triggered Subsystems".